# Does varargin have to be at the end of the input parameter list?

Tags: matlab, function, variadic-functions

I want to define a function that combines two kinds of inputs:

- a given number of regular inputs,
- a variable number of additional inputs, using `varargin`.

Is it correct that I have to put `varargin` at the end of the inputs?

MWE

- function

  ```
  function testfun(st1,st2,varargin)
      strcat(st1,',',st2)
  end
  ```
- main

  `testfun('apple','banana','cherry','date')`

Note that `testfun(varargin,st1,st2)` does not work.

Comment: Yes, this is in [the documentation for `varargin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. varargin must be the last input argument.

[Link to Mathworks documentation on varargin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html#zmw57dd0e766869)